# Kernel panic - not syncing : out of memory and no killable processes when booting after setting GPU memory to 256 MB in raspi-config

Tags: boot, kernel, memory

I tried booting in recovery mode (holding down shift from a USB keyboard attached to the Pi2) and still can't boot to fix.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Reformat the SD card

Comment: I agree with @QuintinBalsdon, the quickest fix is to reformat the SD card. There might be a fix for this, but it would take a bit of tinkering. If you don't have a second Linux Machine it's still fairly easy to backup any important files on the SD card. For Windows you can install DiskInternals Linux Reader which will allow you to make a backup of any of the files on the SD card. I've used it before and it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I had to press Shift when the splash screens appears. Not before. Duh. In config file, gpu_mem was at 64210!!! Changed it to 256. Now it boots.

Comment: This is equivalent to reformatting the card. I actually saw this last night when I used [Apple-Pi Baker](https://www.tweaking4all.com/news/applepi-baker-v1-9-4-update-macos-sierra-beta-2/) to install an image on an SD card - glad you found your answer

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.